# real time gps tracking device

Tags: gps, device, tracking

I am working on a product which requires a real time gps tracking.
I searched on google to collect information, so I got an overview on how does basically GPS work.

Now what else do I need except for a GPS receiver to display on my mobile through an app (designed by us) where a GPS receiver is attached to my product?
I don't want the whole navigation functionality, but just to display where it is located.

I know a GPS receiver continuously sends and receives signals from satellites, but how to display that on my mobile app?
Do we send some info to some kind to a database and then program the app to collect the info from there?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, You need a kind of connection between your receiver and your phone. Since all the phones have their own gps receiver, I assume that you are gonna track the location of a remote device. So the easiest way to do that is creating a basic web service which holds just 2 pages in total.

- 1 to update data by receiver (I suggest you to use a hash key to prevent bots to piss your database)
- 1 to get data to mobile app

Depending on your background and project needs you can either use a database to keep location data or you can use just a file (like xml file or something like that)

Also you will need to parse NMEA code to get the actual data. It is easier to do that on web side (like in php). So you can just pass the NMEA code as it is to server, parse it, record it to database/file. Then you can fetch the data from your mobile app by using simple http requests.

If two devices will be close to each other you can easily use bluetooth but I don't know if there is any case that it make sense to place an additional gps receiver just next to a smart phone :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need some kind of communication channel to send location from your product to a server (1) of directly to the phone (2).

1. Usually GPS tracking devices use GSM modem with GPRS to connection to a remote server. Then your phone app can request location data from server via HTTP API. You can use [open source GPS tracking server](https://github.com/tananaev/traccar) for your project and use some [simple protocol](https://www.traccar.org/traccar-client-protocol/) to send location data to it.
2. Second popular option requires GSM modem again, but in this case device can send SMS messages directly to your phone. In your app you can intercept SMS and retrieve location data.